# Array required but Integer found even when I'm not returning an array

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I'm Writing a class with methods to send questions retrieved from a txt file stored in my computer.
My compiler keeps throwing an error at line 's=op[qno][op];' (The fourth line from the bottom) saying that an "array required but int found" .I'm not even trying to return an array so why am I seeing this? How can I correct it?
    package computerproject;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public final class Questions
{
    String q[]=new String[30];
    String op[][]=new String[55][5];
    int ord[][]=new int[20][5];

     Questions()throws FileNotFoundException,IOException
     {
         initArray();
         setOrder();
     }

     void initArray()throws FileNotFoundException,IOException
     {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new                FileReader("C:\\Users\\mansoor\\Desktop\\Quiz\\Qs.txt"));
        for(int i=0;i<55;i++)
        {
            q[i]=br.readLine();
            op[i][0]=br.readLine();
            System.out.print(op[i][0]);
            op[i][1]=br.readLine();
            op[i][2]=br.readLine();
            op[i][3]=br.readLine();
            op[i][4]=br.readLine();
        }
    }

    void setOrder()
    {
        Random r=new Random();
        for(int i=r.nextInt(55),j=0;j<40;j++,i++)
        {
            ord[j][0]=i%55;
        }
        for(int i=44;i!=0;i--)
        {
            int a=r.nextInt(40);
            int b=r.nextInt(40);
            int t=ord[a][0];
            ord[a][0]=ord[b][0];
            ord[b][0]=t;
            for(int s[]=setRandomOrder(),j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                ord[i][j]=s[j];
            }
        }
    }

    int[] setRandomOrder()
    {
        Random r=new Random();
        int ar[]={0,1,2,3};
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
            int a=r.nextInt(4),b=r.nextInt(4),t;
            t=ar[a];
            ar[a]=ar[b];
            ar[b]=t;
        }
        return ar;
    }

    String sendQuestion(int qno)
    {
        return q[qno];
    }

    String sendCorrectAnswer(int qno)
    {
        return op[qno][4];
    }

    int[] randomOrder()
    {
        Random r=new Random();
        int ar[]=new int[4];
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
            int a=r.nextInt(4);
            int b=r.nextInt(4);
            int t=ar[a];
            ar[a]=ar[b];
            ar[b]=t;
        }
        return ar;
    }

    String[] sendOption(int qno,int op)
    {
        String s[]=new String[4];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            s[i]=op[qno][i];
        }
        return op[qno];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a parameter named `op`; `String[] sendOption(int qno,int op)` <--; which is masking your instance field of the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arent passing in an array to your sendOption method. You're passing in an integer ( op ) , then treating it as your previously declared 2D array when placing the s[i] values in (op[qno][i]). The error could be here. I would change the name of your second input parameter. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your method signature `sendOption(int qno,int op)`. The value `op` is of type `int`. It is not an array that means you can't do stuff like `op[qno][i]`